# Making a Python script run with root privileges

Tags: python, root, sudo, sudoers, visudo

I have a Python script that needs to mount disks on an Ubuntu server without root privileges.
I made the script executable (with `#!/usr/bin/env python`). I also renamed it to '.sh' (probably not important), and `chmod` it to be executable.

Then, I entered the following line to my sudoers file:

```
ALL ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/sazulay/.scripts/mount_disks.sh/
```

If I remove the last '/' ,visudo claims I have a syntax error.

If I leave it like that and run the following line from my user:

```
sudo /home/sazulay/.scripts/mount_disks.sh
```

I am still prompted for password, which was exactly what I was trying to avoid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: `.sh` extension is for shell sripts, `.py` extension is for Python scripts. I suggest you fix this too.

Comment: Thanks Mikko! I only did that because I thought it may have some affect...

Comment: You don't need any extension at all, you are not on ancient DOS/Windows systems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ultrich, I removed any extentions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be a slash at the end of the line. Your sudoers file should look like this,

```
ALL ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/sazulay/.scripts/mount_disks.sh
```

Now, on to your actual problem!

> If I remove the last '/' ,visudo claims I have a syntax error.

I suspect that the line you added is at the end of the file. Now, traditionally, unix commands have a problem if a file does not end with a newline `\n`. Most of the linux editors (that I know off) add this in. There may be a possibility that whatever editor you're using does not. So add an extra line at the end of the file so your line is **not** the last line. So it should be something like this

```
ALL ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/sazulay/.scripts/mount_disks.sh
<--- empty line --->
```